# Passing a reference to an element without assigning an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like several elements to use the same onclick handler, so I have:

```
function close_div() {
    $(this).remove();
}

<div class="closeX" onclick="close_div()">The first div</div>
<div class="closeX" onclick="close_div()"The second div</div>
<div class="closeX" onclick="close_div()"The third div</div>
```

So when you click any div it gets removed from the DOM.

The problem with the code above is that onclick doesn't pass a useful this keyword so close_div() can't use it.  If I gave each `div.closeX` a different **id** I could pass that as `close_div(id)` and do something like   `$("#"+id).remove()`.  But it seems like there should be a way to automatically pass a reference to the element that was clicked, without assigning an id to the element and passing that.  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Even better -- Don't use inline handlers.

```
$('.closeX').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

I'm probably guessing you're creating these elements dynamically, which is why you're wanting to use inline handlers - but we still have a better solution in separating the behaviour and the content.
It's called delegation.

Basically, if you're going to be adding these elements dynamically, you have a static ancestor within the DOM somewhere - and the key is to attach a handler to that.

For example:

```
$('#ancestor-container').on('click', '.closeX', function(e){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: +1 The natural way. However, with jQuery 1.9+, `.on()` needs a context after the event name. It could be set to `null` too. So, `$('.closeX').on('click', null, function(e){ ...`.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour - wow, really? I think I'm showing that I haven't yet updated to 1.9! I'll read the docs now, but will update if you are correct, thanks.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour - Do you have a link to the documentation for that? http://api.jquery.com/on says it's still an optional parameter...

Comment: It *is* optional - my bad. Some time ago I had to replace `.live()` with `.on()` in some plugins and read on a blog that you need the selector after the event name.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm creating the elements dynamically so they're not there when Ready runs. And I don't want to make up ids for every element I create. Your idea of binding the template function with on() was new to me and looks like a good solution, but Arthur's solution of just passing the this keyword from the inline code is clearer and does the trick - div class="closeX" onclick="close_div(this)">The first div</div>, so that's what I'm going with. But thanks for teaching me your method.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the inline event handling and assign something like this,

```
$(".closeX").on("click", close_div);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function close_div(el) {
    $(el).remove();
}

<div class="closeX" onclick="close_div(this)">The first div</div>
<div class="closeX" onclick="close_div(this)"The second div</div>
<div class="closeX" onclick="close_div(this)"The third div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This does exactly what I was asking.